# How to edit existing file with quill editor?

Tags: flutter, dart, editor, document, quill

I am using [Quill Editor](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) to create a document. I want to edit an existing document with in my application. how do I achieve this. Also how can I give some values initially to the quill controller. Something like this, `TextEditingController(text:"example")` When the textfield created the "example" text will be inserted to the text field. how can i achieve this with the quill editor. I want to insert a image and some text like name, age, contact number initially.

**This is my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart';
import 'package:flutter_quill_extensions/flutter_quill_extensions.dart';

class Editor extends StatefulWidget {
  const Editor({super.key});

  @override
  State<Editor> createState() => _EditorState();
}

class _EditorState extends State<Editor> {
  QuillController editorController = QuillController.basic();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          QuillToolbar.basic(
            controller: editorController,
            toolbarIconAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
            embedButtons: FlutterQuillEmbeds.buttons(
              onImagePickCallback: (file) async {
                return file.path;
              },
            ),
            iconTheme: QuillIconTheme(
                iconSelectedFillColor: Colors.green,
                iconUnselectedFillColor: Colors.grey.shade300),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 0),
              child: QuillEditor.basic(
                  embedBuilders: FlutterQuillEmbeds.builders(),
                  controller: editorController,
                  readOnly: false),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may insert data in document at specified index using insert. The data parameter can be either a String or an object extending [Embeddable](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_quill/latest/flutter_quill/Embeddable-class.html). For example, the following inserts passed str at the beginning of the document.

```
void insertStringAtDocumentBeginning(String str){
  editorController.document.insert(0, str);
}
```

call it from initState in order to give some initial values e.g.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    insertStringAtDocumentBeginning('name, age, contact number');
  }
```

As for image, have a look at the concept of embed blocks @ [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill#embed-blocks)

[example folder on github](https://github.com/singerdmx/flutter-quill/tree/master/example) has an app that shows how to embed image and other custom blocks